# browsers do not read new line in a php file

Tags: php, browser

I have a password protected text file and to make it password protected, i used a password protector script (which works great) but it required me to rename the text file to .php on my server. This went fine, however, when I open this text file in any browser on windows, i do not seeing any new lines (I used to see them)

I tried writing -"\n", "\r", "\r\n". I think it has to do with the browser thinking its a .php file i guess.

Comment: How about when you open the file with a text editor?

Comment: thanks a lot everyone, using <br> fixed it.

Comment: "it required me to rename the text file to .php on my server." highly suspicious.

Answer (score 7):

This is because the server is sending a different MIME type.  It is now sending `text/html` (the default type returned by PHP) rather than `text/plain`.

Your browser is then expecting HTML.  Line breaks are just like any other white space in HTML, so they are essentially meaningless for what you are trying to do.

You can use this to fix it:

`header('Content-Type: text/plain');`

Be sure to put that at the top of your code, or at least before you output anything.

This causes the server to send the MIME type you are expecting.

Answer (score 3):

By default the output of PHP scripts are rendered as HTML, which means that whitespace is folded. If you want to change this back to text then you need to set the `Content-Type` header to "text/plain", either in the web server or via the `header()` function.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the browser would see the content as html and in html a newline is just a whitespace

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood your question properly, but in two cases there is a solution:

-You output the text: In this case, you have to use

```
<br>
```

-You want to write it with new lines in the file: Use the PHP-Constant

```
PHP_EOL
```

which means End-of-Line. This inserts always a correct break.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers uses HTML to format text (contained in html of course)

use `<br>` or `<p>`

Also considering your file is a `.php` it's a normal behaviour that your webserver will send it as `text/html`

Comment: No they don't. Browsers use HTML to format HTML. Browsers use text to format text, but you have to _tell_ the browser that it's text.

Comment: @tomalak: In the next few days I am going to report you if you continue to -1 every my answer caught from my profile

Comment: Also as you can see my answer has actually answered the OP

Comment: I have done no such thing. I simply -1 when I see an answer that I think is not right. If I have -1'd your previous answers, then that is because I have disagreed with your previous answers. I am not on any "personal vendetta" against you or anyone else. I don't have the time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<br>`, as html is being rendered in the browser.

Comment: See my comment on Illusionist's answer.